# Erlang demonitor badarg

Tags: erlang, monitor

Here is my function :

```
mydemonitor(Pid) ->
    io:format("Demonitor : ~w ~n", [Pid]),  %%For debugging and trying to see what's wrong
    erlang:demonitor(Pid, [flush]).
```

And here is what I get :

```
Demonitor : <0.41.0>

=ERROR REPORT==== 15-Oct-2014::15:32:19 ===
Error in process <0.47.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,demonitor,[<0.41.0>,[flush]],[]},{node3,mydemonitor,1,[{file,"node3.erl"},{line,213}]},{node3,stabilize,4,[{file,"node3.erl"},{line,147}]},{node3,node,5,[{file,"node3.erl"},{line,46}]}]}
```

I looked at the man of `erlang:demonitor/2` and `erlang:demonitor/1`, it seems that I use the right syntax. I tried to use demonitor/1 (so without the flush option) without success.

I really don't see what is wrong, any idea would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `demonitor/1` and `demonitor/2` is *not* the PID of the process being monitored, but the reference returned by `monitor/2`.

Comment: How could I miss this, it's written everywhere in the man. Thank you very much :)